# How do I open each file in a directory with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need to open each file inside a directory. My attempt at this looks like:

```
Dir.foreach('path/to/directory') do |filename|
  next if filename == '.' || filename == '..'
  puts "working on #{filename}"

  # this is where it crashes
  file = File.open(filename, 'r')

  #some code

  file.close

  # more code

end
```

My code keeps crashing at `File.open(filename, 'r')`. I'm not sure what `filename` should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filename should include the path to the file when the file is not in the same directory than the Ruby file itself:

```
path = 'path/to/directory'
Dir.foreach(path) do |filename|
  next if filename == '.' || filename == '..'

  puts "working on #{filename}"

  file = File.open("#{path}/#{filename}", 'r')

  #some code

  file.close

  # more code
end
```

Comment: I'd not use Dir.foreach because it returns . and .. which you need to filter out. See my Answer with Dir.glob

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [`Find.find`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html).

While we can use various methods from the Dir class, it will look and retrieve the list of files before returning, which can be costly if we're recursively searching multiple directories or have a huge number of files embedded in the directories.

Instead, `Find.find` will walk the directories, returning both the directories and files as each is found. A simple check lets us decide which we want to continue processing or whether we want to skip it. The documentation has this example which should be easy to understand:

> The Find module supports the top-down traversal of a set of file paths.
>
> For example, to total the size of all files under your home directory, ignoring anything in a “dot” directory (e.g. $HOME/.ssh):

```
require 'find'

total_size = 0

Find.find(ENV["HOME"]) do |path|
  if FileTest.directory?(path)
    if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
      Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
    else
      next
    end
  else
    total_size += FileTest.size(path)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for `Dir.glob` or `File.find`. But not `Dir.foreach` as it returns `.` and `..` which you don't want.

```
Dir.glob('something/*').each do |filename|
  next if File.directory?(filename)
  do_something_with_the_file(filename)
end
```

Comment: Thanks spickermann for the cleanup. Lost the connection during my commute and could not fix it myself:-)